# How retrieve version of nested array of objects except one attribute / level (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would like to retrieve a version of an object excluding the details. Or put differentlly I would like to retrieve all except the Trades-element in below nested array of objects.

What would be the best way to do that? The list of attributes on each level is actually much longer then this. Is there a way to copy all except one attribute on a certain level? Or all except one level: leaving Trades but removing its Trade-node)?

```
[{
  "SP": {
    "countOrders": 47,
    "count": 0,
    "Orders": [{
      "81803965": {
        "symbol": "RFX",
        "description": "REDFLOW LTD",
        "Trades": {
          "Trade": [{
            "conId": "81803965",
            "tradeId": "17891517",
            "transactionId": "51996490",
```

I found a way like this:

```
const pfSummary = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(portfolios));
var key;
pfSummary.forEach(function (pf) {
  for (x in pf) {
    key = x;
    break;
  }
  pf[key].Orders.forEach(function (or) {
    for (x in or) {
      key = x;
      break;
    }
    delete or[key].Trades;
  });
});
```

That works. I'm sure there's a better way to do that, e.g. how to properly retrieve an object's key...?

Better solutions please?

Akabin's modified solution:

```
pfSummary.forEach(pf => {
  let pfKey = Object.keys(pf);  
  pf[pfKey].Orders.forEach(or => {
    let orKey = Object.keys(or);
    delete or[orKey].Trades;
  });
});
```

Comment: What would you like your resulting data to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
let pfSummary = [{
  "SP": {
    "countOrders": 47,
    "count": 0,
    "Orders":  [{
      "81803965": {
        "symbol": "RFX",
        "description": "REDFLOW LTD",
        "Trades": {
          "Trade": [{
            "conId": "81803965",
            "tradeId": "17891517",
            "transactionId": "51996490",
          }]
        }
    }
    }]
  }
}]



pfSummary.forEach(el =>{
    let name =  Object.keys(el);
    for (const key of Object.entries(el[name].Orders[0])) {
        delete key[1].Trades['Trade'];
    }
})

console.log('pfSummary', pfSummary)
```

Comment: I'll look into that thanks. SP however is not a key name but a named key just like the keys in the Orders objects.

Comment: Just updated it to include a way to get around the random key name.

Comment: That would only remove the trades from the first Order. But your way of retrieving the key helped me out. Added your modified solution to the question.

Comment: Glad I could help at least get you that far.